# R: Sort elements in a named vector by names

Tags: r, sorting

I have a named character vector, which I would like to sort by names. MWE:

```
# Character vector; assign names
vec <- letters[1:10]
names(vec) <- c(letters[20:11])

> vec
  t   s   r   q   p   o   n   m   l   k 
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" 

# This does not work
> sort(vec)
  t   s   r   q   p   o   n   m   l   k 
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" 

# Desired output
> vec
  k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 
"j" "i" "h" "g" "f" "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` the `names` of `vec` :

```
vec[sort(names(vec))]
#  k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 
#"j" "i" "h" "g" "f" "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
```

You can also use `order` :

```
vec[order(names(vec))]
```